# Importing KML file to OpenLayers - Projection System

Tags: openlayers-2, kml

I know that many have this problem,but none of the answers helped me so i suppose it's a different problem.This is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Lesson Javascript-OpenLayers-WMS</title>
        <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&amp;sensor=false"></script>
        <script src="http://openlayers.org/api/OpenLayers.js"></script> 

        <script>
                    var map;
            var lat_x=23.5552407
            var long_y=41.0746029


            function arxiki() {

                map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
                map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher());
            map.events.register("mousemove", map, function(e) {
                            var position = this.events.getMousePosition(e);
                            OpenLayers.Util.getElement("coords").innerHTML = position;
                        });

                // the SATELLITE layer has all 22 zoom level, so we add it first to
                // become the internal base layer that determines the zoom levels of the
                // map.
                var gsat = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Satellite",
                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: 22,visibility: false}
                );
                var gphy = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Physical",
                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN, visibility: false}
                );
                var gmap = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Streets", // the default
                    {numZoomLevels: 20, visibility: false}
                );
                var ghyb = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
                    "Google Hybrid",
                    {type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: 22,visibility: true}
                );

            /////////////kml layers
                var kml =  new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("KML", {
                        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
                        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                            url: "oikismoiKilkis.kml",
                            projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                            format: new OpenLayers.Format.KML({
                                extractStyles: true, 
                                extractAttributes: true,
                                maxDepth: 2
                            })
                        })
                    });

                    map.addLayers([gsat, gphy, gmap, ghyb,kml]);
                // Google.v3 uses EPSG:900913 as projection, so we have to
                // transform our coordinates
                map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lat_x,long_y).transform(
                    new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
                    map.getProjectionObject()
                ), 7);

                //map.zoomToMaxExtent();  
            }
        </script>

        <!--<script src="google-v3-alloverlays.js"></script>-->
    </head>
    <body onload="arxiki()">

        <div id="map" onmousemove="GetCoords();" style="width:500px;height:300px;outline:1px solid black"></div>
        <label id="coords"></label>

    </body>
</html>
```

Here everything works fine instead of the KML loading part. I have tried running the html from a localhost (IIS 7),running different types of projection (2100,4326),running KML files that others suggested that they work, uploading the KML (GoogleDrive,DropBox) and load it from online, even different loaders like the GML Loader using as format .KML .

What am I doing wrong and as an extra question is the conversion from different types of projection system happening automatically like in Google Earth?

Comment: I don't see any projection definition for the map object. It should be EPSG:900913 or EPSG:3857.

Comment: Thanks for response AndreJ.. I have changed the the map definition to     map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913"),displayProjection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG: 4326")}); but still no result.Did you manage to make it work somehow? I have been searching the hole night.. :/

Comment: I have just converted one of my GPX files to kml with QGIS, put it in the same local folder and it gets displayed. Maybe your kml file references to something that does not exist. Can you insert the dropbox link?

Comment: soory for the delay..was searching. THAT'S GREAT NEWS :D! here's the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/wvx2j8xmvn9rssr/oikismoiKilkis.kml?dl=0) . What coord system did you use to export? and did you change the map definition?

Comment: Downloaded to disk it works for me too in Firefox, except that it does not align with anything. I used EPSG:4326 (as all GPX data uses it). Openlayers does not like much other CRS than 4326 and 900913. I took the unchanged html from your question.

Comment: The thing is that when i use [this](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/examples/drag-and-drop.html) example to drag and drop the kml it gets displayed so i think that there is no problem with the kml. This example uses ol3 library. What do you think I am doing wrong?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19279/discussion-between-mrapsogos-and-andrej).

Comment: Can you try if http://home.arcor.de/andre.joost/test.htm works for you? If not, it is a browser restriction on your side.

Comment: yeah just saw that..i logged with linux and it worked..I was using the new mozilla developer edition and maybe there is a problem with that! :D  Thanks for the research!